# reformat an xml file

Tags: xml, bash, xslt, awk

I have the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Data xmlns="http://www.test.com">
        <form Name="Group1">
            <Period Time="19042016T08:35:00"/>
            <Type c="1">Load</Type>
            <Type c="2">Memory</Type>
            <Type c="3">CPU</Type>
            <Type c="4">Task</Type>
            <Value Item="M-1">
                <val c="1">2979</val>
                <val c="2">0</val>
                <val c="3">9599</val>
                <val c="4">0</val>
            </Value>
            <Value Item="M-2">
                <val c="1">2973</val>
                <val c="2">0</val>
                <val c="3">0</val>
                <val c="4">0</val>
            </Value>
            <Value Item="M-3">
                <val c="1">2985</val>
                <val c="2">11889</val>
                <val c="3">0</val>
                <val c="4">0</val>
            </Value>
            <Value Item="M-4">
                <val c="1">28</val>
                <val c="2">0</val>
                <val c="3">0</val>
                <val c="4">2980</val>
            </Value>
        </form>
        <form Name="Group2">
            <Period Time="19042016T08:35:00"/>
            <Type c="1">Process</Type>
            <Type c="2">User</Type>
            <Type c="3">command</Type>
            <Type c="4">priority</Type>
            <Value Item="M-1">
                <val c="1">0</val>
                <val c="2">0</val>
                <val c="3">0</val>
                <val c="4">4477</val>
            </Value>
            <Value Item="M-2">
                <val c="1">0</val>
                <val c="2">0</val>
                <val c="3">0</val>
                <val c="4">4540</val>
            </Value>
            <Value Item="M-3">
                <val c="1">0</val>
                <val c="2">0</val>
                <val c="3">0</val>
                <val c="4">4526</val>
            </Value>
            <Value Item="M-4">
                <val c="1">0</val>
                <val c="2">0</val>
                <val c="3">0</val>
                <val c="4">4445</val>
            </Value>
        </form>
    </Data>
```

And I would like to have an output as follows:

```
Group=Group1, Time=19042016T08:35:00    
             M-1        M-2         M-3         M-4     
Load        2979       2973        2985          28
Memory         0          0       11889           0
CPU         9599          0           0           0
Task           0          0           0        2980

Name=Group2, Time=19042016T08:35:00    
             M-1        M-2         M-3         M-4     
Process        0          0           0           0
User           0          0           0           0
command        0          0           0           0
priority    4477       4540        4445        4445
```

By looking at some xsltproc examples as suggested here. I came up with the following stylesheet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:t="http://www.test.com">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/t:Data">
        <xsl:for-each select="t:form">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('Group=', @Name, ', Time=',t:Period/@Time,'&#xA;')"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="t:Type">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('CounterName=', text(), '&#xA;')"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="t:Value">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('Machine=', @Item, '&#xA;')"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="t:val">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('CounterValue=', text(), '&#xA;')"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then the result is as follows:

```
xsltproc.exe tx.xsl data.xml 
Group=Group1, Time=19042016T08:35:00
CounterName=Load
CounterName=Memory
CounterName=CPU
CounterName=Task
Machine=M-1
CounterValue=2979
CounterValue=0
CounterValue=9599
CounterValue=0
Machine=M-2
CounterValue=2973
CounterValue=0
CounterValue=0
CounterValue=0
Machine=M-3
CounterValue=2985
CounterValue=11889
CounterValue=0
CounterValue=0
Machine=M-4
CounterValue=28
CounterValue=0
CounterValue=0
CounterValue=2980
Group=Group2, Time=19042016T08:35:00
CounterName=Process
CounterName=User
CounterName=command
CounterName=priority
Machine=M-1
CounterValue=0
CounterValue=0
CounterValue=0
CounterValue=4477
Machine=M-2
CounterValue=0
CounterValue=0
CounterValue=0
CounterValue=4540
Machine=M-3
CounterValue=0
CounterValue=0
CounterValue=0
CounterValue=4526
Machine=M-4
CounterValue=0
CounterValue=0
CounterValue=0
CounterValue=4445
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can get from the result of the xsltproc to the desired output above. Can it be done with a different stylesheet or I will need a post-processing script to be applied after the result of the current stylesheet?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Can you use XSLT 1.0? Like `xsltproc`?

Comment: Your best shot is an xslt file, processed with `xsltproc`

Comment: I don't have xsltproc, got this    -bash: xsltproc: command not found, unfortunately I am not allowed to install any extra tools on this machine.

Comment: Do you have installed python?

Comment: Yes python is installed. I never used python before though :-(

Comment: While `xsltproc` is usually installed to "normal" dirs like `/usr/bin`, you may find it available someplace else. Allow for an overnight search and run `find / -name xlstproc 2>/dev/null` . Good luck.

Comment: xsltproc is not installed, but I can have it on a different machine then ssh to one that has the xmls, I guess xsltproc is the way to go. I am looking for examples in web now.

Comment: @CarlosL Entiendo que por tu nombre hablas español, no? Te he puesto una solución en python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a tab-delimited "table" for each `form`, try the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:t="http://www.test.com">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/t:Data">
    <xsl:for-each select="t:form">
        <!-- table header -->
        <xsl:text>Name=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
        <xsl:text>, Time=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="t:Period/@Time"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;&#10;</xsl:text>
        <!-- column headers -->
        <xsl:for-each select="t:Value">
            <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@Item"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <!-- rows -->
        <xsl:for-each select="t:Type">
            <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
            <!-- row header -->
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <!-- row values -->
            <xsl:for-each select="../t:Value">
                <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="t:val[$i]"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result, applied to your example input, will be:

```
Name=Group1, Time=19042016T08:35:00

    M-1 M-2 M-3 M-4
Load    2979    2973    2985    28
Memory  0   0   11889   0
CPU 9599    0   0   0
Task    0   0   0   2980

Name=Group2, Time=19042016T08:35:00

    M-1 M-2 M-3 M-4
Process 0   0   0   0
User    0   0   0   0
command 0   0   0   0
priority    4477    4540    4526    4445
```

which, with proper tab spacing (here: 10 spaces per tab), will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Michael. I got the following output from your proposal.    
xsltproc.exe ty.xsl data.xml 
Name=Group1, Time=19042016T08:35:00

        M-1     M-2     M-3     M-4
Load    2979    2973    2985    28
Memory  0       0       11889   0
CPU     9599    0       0       0
Task    0       0       0       2980

Name=Group2, Time=19042016T08:35:00

        M-1     M-2     M-3     M-4
Process 0       0       0       0
User    0       0       0       0
command 0       0       0       0
priority        4477    4540    4526    4445

Comment: @CarlosL Please don't post code in comments. I have added the result obtained by my code to my answer. If you need to something else, please edit your question and clarify there.

Comment: xsltproc.exe ty.xsl data.xml 
   
Name=Group2, Time=19042016T08:35:00

                M-1     M-2     M-3     M-4
Process       0       0       0       0
User            0       0       0       0
command    0       0       0       0
priority             4477    4540    4526    4445


Is it possible to capture the length of type and use it before formatting to avoid what happens in the last row with priority?.    
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Got the answer, thanks so much, I appreciate your help.